# How to auto-generate simple CRUD controllers and views in ASP.Net MVC 2 (VS2010) Entity Framework project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I have a standard template "ASP.NET MVC 2 Web application" solution, an empty (meaning no data inserted, but with all tables etc. ready and waiting) SQL Server database, an Entity Framework 4 model (edmx). Is there a way to generate simple CRUD controllers and form views for all the entities in the model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A buddy out there helped me with the answer - the answer is to use a "ASP.NET Dynamic Data Entities Web Application" instead of "ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application" project template. The rest is 1-2-3-easy and is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. His question was how to do this with MVC, not .NET.
I too would like to hook up and generate MVC user forms from a Sql Server schema.