# Best asp.net crud solutions?

Tags: asp.net, crud

what's the best way to implement a simple crud solutions in ASP.NET ? 
Something simple, without control ?
Any ready solutions ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic Data](http://www.asp.net/dynamicdata)

Answer (score 4):

[SQLDataSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.aspx) + [DataGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.aspx) = Instant CRUD app

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic Data.

See another article on stackoverflow:

[How to auto-generate simple CRUD controllers and views in ASP.Net MVC 2 (VS2010) Entity Framework project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2692624/how-to-auto-generate-simple-crud-controllers-and-views-in-asp-net-mvc-2-vs2010)